# How can I record a 45-minute concert using my iPhone (storage!!)

Tags: iphone, video, storage

I want to make a simple video recording of a 45-minute concert using my iPhone XS (iOS 16.6) but there is only 20GB of storage available.  I understand that my recording will use more than 20GB.

I have an iCloud account with oodles of space.  Can I record directly to the iCloud?  If so, how?

Comment: How much space does a 1 minute video require? How much  storage exists on your phone? backup all the other data and maximise the storage available, also backup & remove downloaded apps. How many minutes can you then store?

Comment: @SolarMike - 45 minutes of video requires around 60GB!  My phone has 64GB total!

Comment: Video size depends on the compression you get, which depends on the things you record. Details are a bit difficult, but more action/movement on the stage means less compression (very simplified). So if you really expect the video to be (close to) 60 GB you'll need a dedicated video/photo camera.

Comment: FullHD will be way smaller as I mentioned below, maybe you can setup compression and so on in an alternate camera app.

Answer (score 2):

With the nativ iOS camera App there is no way to record directly onto external storage. You would need a different Camera App which is recording to a place of your choice (if this even exists)

But in FullHD your iPhone storage should be sufficient

With these assumptions, you can estimate the size of a 45-minute Full HD video recording as follows:

Video Bitrate (Mbps) = 15 Mbps (assuming an average bitrate)
Video Duration (minutes) = 45 minutes
File Size (GB) = (Video Bitrate / 8) x (Video Duration / 60)

Plugging in the values:

File Size (GB) = (15 Mbps / 8) x (45 minutes / 60) = 8.4375 GB

So, a 45-minute Full HD video recording at 15 Mbps bitrate would be approximately 8.44 gigabytes (GB) in size.

Also you can outsource apps into iCloud (done in the settings) to free up additional space.